# Does Firebase support multiple subdomains?

Tags: firebase, dns, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a website development, right now I have the site up and live in Firebase.

The thing is that I need to add a folder but this need to be in a subdomain, i.e,

Domain: example.firebaseapp.com with all the assets and things that my website needs. 
subdomain: design-explorer.example.firebaseapp.com Here is where I have to add the new folder.

Is it possible do this? I have been reading the documentation but there is no information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Hosting does not currently support hosting multiple subdomains in subfolders of the same project.

The only option at the moment is to host each subdomain on a separate project.

Comment: Do you mean create a new project and there add the subdomain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase doesn't know the relation between the project. What makes you think it should?